# GlobalLock and Global memory in kernel mode?

Tags: memory, kernel, driver

How to use globallock in kernel mode?

A driver linked with kernel32.lib always give me system error 127.(The environment is correct)

How could I use it or is there anything working in kernel mode?

Answer (score 1):

Global/local memory doesn't make any sense in kernel mode.

You might want to use `ExAllocatePoolWithTag` for kernel memory allocation.

Comment: I need to read global memory. Some functions are giving HGLOBAL

Comment: @iamsleepy: A *kernel* -mode function giving you back `HGLOBAL`? What function is this?

Comment: @iamsleepy: Wait, doesn't that [function](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:29FzJvzVMSMJ:doxygen.reactos.org/d3/d69/include_2reactos_2win32k_2ntuser_8h_a314cda50c819850d47c4c1814a5a0dea.html+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) return the same buffer that you give it? Why is HGLOBAL necessary?

Comment: It returns a handle. I've got no idea how to deal with it(ObReferenceObjectByHandle was my first idea, and not working). In user mode, it is HGLOBAL for sure. Any advices?

Comment: I checked, second parameter (PVOID pParam) looks like a struct with format and some other information.

Comment: @iamsleepy: Oh wow, I have no idea... I'll post here if I find anything. (Taking a look at [ReactOS](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d3/d69/include_2reactos_2win32k_2ntuser_8h_ac72bb0754d8bb17cd40fa34c462db627.html#ac72bb0754d8bb17cd40fa34c462db627) right now...)

Comment: I almost forget to look into reactos. After a short research, I'll try NtUserCreateLocalMemHandle later. I think it would work.

Comment: @iamsleepy: It *looks* as though you may be able to just call `RtlFreeHeap` and such, directly on the handle -- assuming it's locked. But I haven't tried this, so be careful!

Comment: NtUserCreateLocalMemHandle will do the work. Hooray! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The way to convert a HGLOBAL handle to pointer in kernel mode is NtUserCreateLocalMemHandle located in Shadow SSDT.
After read code from reactos, it could be done like this.

```
 HANDLE hRetVal;
    PVOID mem = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status;
    PDWORD size = NULL;
    DWORD dwordsize = 4;
    DWORD realsize = 0;
    KAPC_STATE apcstate;

    ZwAllocateVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &size, 0, &dwordsize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)
    KeStackAttachProcess(PsGetCurrentProcess(),&apcstate)
    hRetVal = NtUserGetClipboardData(uFormat, pParam);//I am calling it in my hook
    status = NtUserCreateLocalMemHandle(hRetVal, NULL, 0, size);
    realsize = *size;
    if(status == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL)
    {
      ZwAllocateVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(),&mem,0,size,MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE);
      status = NtUserCreateLocalMemHandle(hRetVal, mem, realsize, NULL);
      ZwFreeVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(),&mem,size,MEM_DECOMMIT)
    }
   if(mem != NULL)
   {
      ZwFreeVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(),&size,&dwordsize,MEM_DECOMMIT);
   }
   KeUnstackDetachProcess(&apcstate);
```

...Free memory and something else.